# Dynamic SELECT TOP @var In SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How can I have a dynamic variable setting the amount of rows to return in SQL Server? Below is not valid syntax in SQL Server 2005+:

```
DECLARE @count int
SET @count = 20

SELECT TOP @count * FROM SomeTable
```

Comment: Are you running SQL 2005 or 2008?

Comment: Running SQL Server 2005 currently

Answer (score 686, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (@count) * FROM SomeTable
```

This will only work with SQL 2005+

Comment: I always forget the parentheses too.

Comment: why are the parentheses necessary?

Answer (score 43):

The syntax "select top (@var) ..." only works in SQL SERVER 2005+. For SQL 2000, you can do:

```
set rowcount @top

select * from sometable

set rowcount 0
```

Hope this helps

Oisin.

(edited to replace @@rowcount with rowcount - thanks augustlights)

Comment: I've heard that it is possible to get incorrect row number with @@RowCount if you have multi-column primary key. Is that true?

Answer (score 14):

In x0n's example, it should be:

```
SET ROWCOUNT @top

SELECT * from sometable

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Answer (score 8):

```
declare @rows int = 10

select top (@rows) *
from Employees
order by 1 desc -- optional to get the last records using the first column of the table
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you just put the variable in parenthesis

```
DECLARE @top INT = 10;

SELECT TOP (@Top) *
FROM <table_name>;
```

Answer (score 4):

Its also possible to use dynamic SQL and execute it with the exec command:

```
declare @sql  nvarchar(200), @count int
set @count = 10
set @sql = N'select top ' + cast(@count as nvarchar(4)) + ' * from table'
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: But be (very) wary of [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) with this approach