# Variable as top value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

```
declare @num as int set @num = 5

select top @num col1, col2 from table1
```

The above does not work.  It does not like @num being used that way.  What needs to be done so I can have a variable value next to the top command?

It gives the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '@num'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic SELECT TOP @var In SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175962/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP (@num) a FROM table
```

SQL server 2005 onwards, this is supported to parameterize TOP.

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server 2000 onwards:

```
declare @num as int 
set @num = 5  

SET ROWCOUNT @num 

select col1, col2 from table1 

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

**UPDATE**: Actually, are you sure this doesn't work (I don't have a 2005 instance available):

```
declare @num as int 
set @num = 5  

select TOP (@num) col1, col2 from table1 
-- Implictly in clustered index order...
```

Comment: That should - the syntax is just to wrap the variable in a ().

Comment: your updated version works because you have parentheses, that it what the OP is missing :)

Answer (score 4):

In parenthesis

```
declare @num as int set @num = 5

select top (@num) col1, col2 from table1
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap the variable in parentheses

```
declare @num int 

set @num = 5

select top (@num) col1, col2 from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string concatenation and sp_executesql is one way to achieve that ...

declare @num as int set @num = 5

```
declare @sql varchar(255)
select @sql = 'select top ' + @num + ' col1, col2 from table1'
sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @num AS INT 
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
SET @num = 5  
SET @SQL = N'select top ' + CAST(@num AS VARCHAR(5)) + ' col1, col2 from table1'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

try using dynamic SQL

something like this

```
declare @dynamicsql nvarchar(4000);
declare @num as int;
set @num = 5

set @dynamicsql = 'select top ' + convert(nvarchar, @num) + ' col1, col2 from table1';
exec @dynamicsql;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use dynamic SQL, or you can rewrite the entire SQL to use some kind of ROWNUMBER trick, not sure which one will be best performance-wise.

For "dynamic SQL", you need to build your SQL in a string and then execute it.

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520123828/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-use-a-variable-in-a-top-clause-in-sql-server.html) for details.