# Syntax error in SPs

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic SELECT TOP @var In SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175962/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server)

why am I getting a syntax error at `select top @recNo` here?

```
create procedure getTopAccounts
(
@recNo int
)
as
begin
    select top 1 accDesc, accNum 
    from
      (select top @recNo accDesc,accNum
      from 
      ACCOUNTS_TABLE
      order by
      accNum desc)
    as a order by accNum
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
...select top (@recNo) accDesc...
```

Parametrised [TOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) needs to be in parenthesis