# Query for last 10 minutes if > 300 records OR last 300 records

Tags: sql, sql-server

We currently have a table that logs traffic through our service.  We're looking for a way to do some diagnostics/alerts based on the traffic, but find that at 2am we don't have enough traffic to be reliable (1 fail at 2 am can be a 50% failure rate, but at 9am when people work up, 1 fail can be .01%).

We'd like to check on the last 10 minutes by server, if the last 10 minutes doesn't have 300 records in it, we'd like to go back until we have 300 records.

Is there a way to do this in a query?

Our table looks like:

```
ID INT,
ServerID INT,
Success BIT,
ActionDate DATETIME
```

I could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the last 300, but if the traffic is high enough that this isn't the full last 10 minutes, we're missing data that might be relevant.

I'm looking to do something along the lines of

```
SET _RowCount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE Date >= DATEADD(M, -10, GETDATE()); 
IF _RowCount < 300 SET @RowCount = 300;  
SELECT TOP _RowCount records
```

But can't seem to use a variable as the TOP count.

Comment: Are you looking to get all records (300+) within the last 10 minutes

Comment: I'm looking to get the last 10 minutes of messages or if there are not 300 messages in the last 10 minutes, the last 300 messages.

Comment: @gunr2171 Sorry, code is moved into the main question

Comment: You might try [`SET ROWCOUNT 300`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx) and then `SELECT` the last 10 minutes of data.

Comment: `TOP` can be used with a variable, it just requires parentheses: `TOP ( @Rows )`.  [Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx#BasicSyntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the last 300 records seems like the easiest thing to do:

```
SELECT top 300 t.*
FROM tbl t
order by date desc;
```

But you can do what you want with a single query:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date desc) as seqnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 300 or Date >= DATEADD(M, -10, GETDATE());
```

Comment: If you're getting 300+ records added to the table every 10 minutes (no indication on retention), would you want to row_number the whole table? Would that hurt performance?

Comment: This is an interesting solution and neater than creating a variable and using it.  Like Greg said, it is a major hit on the server when run on the whole table, but not bad if we assume 300 records in a 4 hour period

Comment: +1 for correct answer; If performance is an issue can you provide the columns in the table and the indexes on these columns? If you have an index on `Date` this should be fine for you; all your limiting criteria comes back to that column and SQL Server should be able to figure this out as long as your statistics are up to date.

Comment: I'm definitely going with this one with a 4 hour "assumption" to keep the time down (since in the last 12 months we've never gone below that).  One minor change, the short version of Minute is "MI" not "M" which is month.  I couldn't figure out why I was getting a couple million rows for a minute there.

Answer (score 0):

Not as neat as yours, but:

```
SET @RowCount = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl WHERE Date >= DATEADD(M, -10, GETDATE()); 

IF @RowCount < 300 
BEGIN
  SELECT TOP 300 records order by Date Desc
END
ELSE
  SELECT records WHERE Date >= DATEADD(M, -10, GETDATE())
END
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will allow you to use a variable or a query for the TOP parameter if enclosed in parentheses.

So

```
SELECT (@RowCount) * FROM tbl
```

works while

```
SELECT @RowCount * FROM tbl
```

does not

Thanks to StackOverflow for: [Dynamic SELECT TOP @var In SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175962/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server) I can use a variable and do an if to make it the proper value.

Thanks