# How to insert top selecting number as a parameter in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get top 10, top 5 records of a table time to time. So I'm gonna create a stored procedure with a parameter which is accepting the number of records as the parameter. But it gives me an error near @number in the query.

This is what i tried, this gives me a syntax error:

> error=Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure selectVoterTopGivenNumberRECS, Line 10 Incorrect syntax near '@number'.

Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE selectVoterTopGivenNumberRECS
  (
    @number int
  )
AS 
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
--Query

 SELECT TOP @number 

V.NICorPP as NICorPP,V.fName+' '+V.mName+' '+V.lName AS Name,
V.DOB AS DateofBirth,
CASE (V.gender) 

  WHEN 1 THEN 'Male'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'Female' 
  END  AS Gender,V.vtaddress AS VoterAddress,V.phHome AS ContactHome,
   V.phMob AS  ContactMobile,V.occupation AS Occupation, 
  V.occRegID AS RegisteredOCCID,LGD.LGDivName
FROM Voter V
INNER JOIN LGDivision LGD ON V.lgDiv=LGD.LGDivID
   WHERE V.vtStatus='Active'; 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
END;
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: Could you please include the error you received?  Looks like you didnt quite finish that sentence.

Comment: @paqogomez error=Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure selectVoterTopGivenNumberRECS, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near '@number'.

Comment: Please see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175962/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add brackets around the `parameter`

```
SELECT TOP (@number) V.NICorPP                               AS NICorPP,
                           V.fName + ' ' + V.mName + ' ' + V.lName AS NAME,
                           V.DOB                                   AS DateofBirth,
                           CASE V.gender
                             WHEN 1 THEN 'Male'
                             WHEN 2 THEN 'Female'
                           END                                     AS Gender,
                           V.vtaddress                             AS VoterAddress,
                           V.phHome                                AS ContactHome,
                           V.phMob                                 AS ContactMobile,
                           V.occupation                            AS Occupation,
                           V.occRegID                              AS RegisteredOCCID,
                           LGD.LGDivName
      FROM   Voter V
             INNER JOIN LGDivision LGD
                     ON V.lgDiv = LGD.LGDivID
      WHERE  V.vtStatus = 'Active';
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add parameter to the variable,change the

```
SELECT TOP @number
```

for

```
 SELECT TOP (@number)
```