# Having an int as a sql parameter

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, parameters, sqldatasource

I'm using a sql data source in asp.net, trying to have a variable here

```
SELECT TOP  @Number *
From Table
```

I want the variable to be from a dropdown that postsback on the same page. All the options in that dropdown are ints. How do I add the parameter? The DataSource.SelectParameters.Add() method only takes a string input

Comment: Side note - SQL query is somewhat suspicious - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175962/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server, but lack of code showing how you actually execute the query makes it hard to guess answer correctly...

Comment: Its not complicated. I jsut want it to be top4 or top 5 depending on the selection. Rest of the query works fine

Answer (score 0):

> The DataSource.SelectParameters.Add() method only takes a string input?

No. You can provide any type of value and you have to use [`SQLDbType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) to  specify parameter type.

Based on your comments to my answer.

```
var s = MealNumberDD.Text;

var param = new SQLParameter("MealNumber", SQLDbType.Int)
{
    Value = Convert.ToInt32(s)
};

RecipesDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(param); 
var query = "SELECT TOP (@MealNumber) * FROM Recipes"; 
RecipesDataSource.SelectCommand = query;
```

Comment: I cant conver from sqlparameter to webcontrol.parameter

Comment: var param = new SqlParameter("MealNumber", Int32.Parse(MealNumberDD.SelectedValue));
       
        RecipesDataSource.SelectParameters.Add(param);

        RecipesDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT TOP  @MealNumber* FROM Recipes ";

Comment: Add () around parameter like `select (@MealNumber) from Recipes` . See my answer and let me know results.

Comment: So we're ver close. this is my code so far:  var s = MealNumberDD.Text;
         RecipesDataSource.SelectParameters.Add("MealNumber", DbType.Int32,s);
        
     
        var query = "SELECT TOP (@MealNumber)* FROM Recipes";
        RecipesDataSource.SelectCommand = query; For some reason, when I put in s, the code runs, I select a number in the dropdown, and nothing happens. But when I put "3" instead of s as the parameter, it functions as it should

Comment: That means the problem is converting from `DropDown.Text` to `s`. It could be that when data does not populate in `s`, it is treated as 0 and no data is returned.

Comment: that isnt the problem ive tried it. Ive gone through the debugger, its passing the information as expeceted

Comment: Don't use this way to pass parameter. Use like i have done in answer.

Comment: In your way it is treated as `string` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491445(v=vs.110).aspx