# Using subtraction of two queries in SELECT TOP query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to prepare a query like this in SQL Server:

- I have a table where I have a specific, constant value, let's say it's 15 (column defined as `float`)
- In the same table I have one column where sometimes there is a value and sometimes it is a NULL value

So I would like to use `SELECT TOP ()` query that would show me the number of records that is a result of subtraction of two queries:

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Records 
     FROM Brand.Alle
     WHERE HdNummer = '33')
    -
    (SELECT COUNT(AbrufNr) 
     FROM Brand.Alle
     WHERE HdNummer = '33' 
       AND Transaction IS NOT NULL) AS DIFFERENCE
```

This query returns the result I want to have (let's say 13).

I would like to have selected top 13 records from a table I run a query against:

```
SELECT TOP (SELECT 
                (SELECT DISTINCT Records FROM Brand.Alle
                 WHERE HdNummer = '33')
                -
                (SELECT COUNT(AbrufNr) FROM Brand.Alle
                 WHERE HdNummer = '33' AND Transaction IS NOT NULL) AS DIFFERENCE) * 
FROM Brand.Alle
WHERE HdNummer = '33' AND Transaction IS NULL
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

but it fails due to an error saying that I need to use an integer in select top statement. So the question is: how can I convert the value I receive as a result of subtraction two queries so I could use in in `SELECT TOP`?

I would highly appreciate any help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can get the result into a variable and use the solution from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175962/dynamic-select-top-var-in-sql-server

Comment: `row_number() ... < (select ...)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh, I am using SQL Server 2019

Comment: This looks wrong. Do you mean `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Records)` instead of `SELECT DISTINCT Records` maybe? `Records` is a column name, yes?

Comment: And your explanation could be much better. "I have a table where I have a specific, constant value" - A table with a constant value? How is that? Does the table only have one row or what are you talking about? "let's say it's 15 (column defined as float)" - well, 15 is an integer, and why would you use float in a database? It's an approximate data type and your 15 may become 14.00000001. Where is that 15 in your query? I see the string '33'. Why is it a string? You say there is a result, e.g. 13. Still no 15. Where is it? ...

Comment: "In the same table I have one column where sometimes there is a value ..." What is the name of that column? Where is it in your query? Your request would benefit from you showing sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number all your rows and only keep those with a number less or equal to the desired count.

```
with numbered as
(
  select
    alle.*,
    row_number() over (order by newid()) as rn
  from brand.alle
  where hdnummer = 33
)
select * 
from numbered
where rn <= ( <your count query here> );
```

Your count query can probably written shorter along the lines of:

```
select 
  count(distinct records) - 
  count(case when transaction is not null then abrufnr end) as cnt
from brand.alle
where hdnummer = 33;
```

And you can even combine the two with window functions in order to read from the table only once.

```
with numbered_and_counted as
(
  select 
    alle.*,
    count(distinct records) over () - 
    count(case when transaction is not null then abrufnr end) over () as cnt,
    row_number() over (order by newid()) as rn
  from brand.alle
  where hdnummer = 33
) 
select *
from numbered_and_counted
where rn <= cnt;
```